# Comparison of two numbers of different length

Tags: circuit-design, integrated-circuit, comparator, binary

I want to design a circuit at block level using IC 7485 to compare one 6 bit number with another 5 bit number.

My approach is:

- Put the most significant bits into the four 7485 comparator inputs. The 5-bit number will be extended to 6 bits, with the new bit 6 connected to GND.
- Design a 2-bit comparator for the least 2 significant bits of the two numbers and use their output as my input to the IC.

Is this approach correct?

This is a homework question and I would be glad to provide further clarifications. Any advice on how to proceed further would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `want to design [some circuit] using [some component] [for] [some purpose]` rings odd. I miss a solid specification of the observable behaviour required.

Comment: @greybeard, the specification seems sufficiently very clear: *"design a circuit at block level using IC 7485 to compare one 6 bit number with another 5 bit number"* Sorry, are you saying you're having difficulty with that specification?

Comment: (@TonyM: I say that specification is nowhere near complete: I give you a black box with (GND&) 11 inputs, claiming it does *compare…*. How would anyone prove it doesn't? There is to be some *specified* output - indicators flipped/lid/sounded, signals to be observed, change in power consumed - whatever is verifiable.)

Comment: @greybeard, thankfully the actual engineering world don't operate like that, though, not moving til a complete document suitable for manf, test and long-term support is complete, otherwise we'd never get anything done. Some industries don't move until they have a phone-book thick spec' to start with because of their critical circumstances. I've worked in both sides, and for clients large and small. Engineering's about practicality and pragmatism, rather than perfection, excess and waste. Here, I found it perfectly sufficient to describe the situation the OP's in and what they're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your approach will work.  I will mention that there are 8-bit magnitude comparators such as the 682 or 684 as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options I can imagine. I already understand that a 7485 should be used. But is that to be just one? I'll assume so, since otherwise you'd just use two of them.

Let's assume for now that \$P\$ is the 5-bit unsigned value and that \$Q\$ is the 6-bit unsigned value.

- As you mentioned, you can consider the idea of developing a 2-bit comparator for the lower 2 bits of \$P\$ and \$Q\$ to generate the \$P\lt Q\$, \$P=Q\$, and \$P\gt Q\$ inputs to the 7485. As you say, you'd set pin 15 of the 7485 (\$P_3\$ on the IC) to zero ('0') in order to extend \$P\$ to a 6-bit size. That will work. Your task in this case would be to develop the 2-bit comparator logic that would generate the value inputs for pins 2, 3, and 4 of the 7485.
- Another option would be to use the 7485 to compare bits \$P_1\dots P_4\$ with \$Q_1\dots Q_4\$, leaving the added external logic to deal with \$P_0\$, \$Q_0\$, and \$Q_5\$, separately. In this case, you only need to examine \$P_0\$ and \$Q_0\$ to generate the \$P\lt Q\$, \$P=Q\$, and \$P\gt Q\$ inputs to the 7485. This is relatively simple to do. At least, conceptually. That gets you a 5-bit comparison. But it also means that you cannot directly use the \$P\lt Q\$, \$P=Q\$, and \$P\gt Q\$ outputs from the 7485. Instead, the added complexity here is that you would use \$Q_5\$ so that if \$Q_5=1\$ then \$P\lt Q\$ is asserted and forwarded, \$P=Q\$, and \$P\gt Q\$ are de-asserted and forwarded, and the 7485's status outputs are ignored. If \$Q_5=0\$ then the 7485's \$P\lt Q\$, \$P=Q\$, and \$P\gt Q\$ outputs would be forwarded, unchanged.

You can (and should) consider which of these two (or other ideas you may think of) is better for your homework purposes.

But hopefully the above gets you thinking a little more about some different ways to approach the problem.